# List transformation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a list like:

```
a = ['AB', ['CD', 'DE'], 'FG']
```

How do I transform it to a 2D list as shown:

```
[['AB', 'CD', 'FG'], ['AB', 'DE', 'FG']]
```

Using itertools.product also expands 'AB' to 'A', 'B'.

Comment: No, that gives [('A', 'CD', 'F'), ('A', 'CD', 'G'), ('A', 'DE', 'F'), ('A', 'DE', 'G'), ('B', 'CD', 'F'), ('B', 'CD', 'G'), ('B', 'DE', 'F'), ('B', 'DE', 'G')]

Comment: The only one example is not clear enough to know what you need to do in the general case: can you have more nested lists, with various depth? How would you handle them?

Comment: No, there is only two level of nesting.

Comment: But can you have for example `['AB',['CD',EF'],['GH','IJ','KL']]`?

Comment: No. There can be only list with in the parent list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` as follows:

```
>>> list(itertools.product(*(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in a)))
[('AB', 'CD', 'FG'), ('AB', 'DE', 'FG')]
```

Here we simply take the `product`, where we first transform singletons such as `'AB'` into a list `['AB']`.

If you require a list of lists for your output, simply transform them:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in itertools.product(
...      *(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in a))]
[['AB', 'CD', 'FG'], ['AB', 'DE', 'FG']]
```

Comment: Damn you just beat me at it! :)

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to keep it a list of list instead of a list of tuple.

Comment: of course, do you wish me to do *all* the work?

Comment: I remember in my first days, Googling how to get a list of this to a list of that, and a list of that to a list of the other, and split, and join, and blah blah. Oh, and then...regex can do it all! And later...no! Don't use regex! *Hehe...*

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  if type(a[i]) is list:
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
      b.append(a[:i] + [a[i][j]] + a[i+1:])
```